# What does the indent change in this kind of code?

Tags: printing, indentation

Newbie here. I understand that for Python, indentation is extremely important. However, I'm having trouble understanding what the indent tells Python to do differently.

In this block of code,

```
smallest_till_now=0

for num in [-1,-2,5,4,-10,9]:
  if num<smallest_till_now:
    smallest_till_now=num
  print(smallest_till_now,num)
```

I get

```
-1 -1
-2 -2
-2 5
-2 4
-10 -10
-10 9
```

But for this block of code:

```
smallest_till_now=0

for num in [-1,-2,5,4,-10,9]:
  if num<smallest_till_now:
    smallest_till_now=num
    print(smallest_till_now,num)
```

I get this:

```
-1 -1
-2 -2
-10 -10
```

The only difference is the level of indent for the print(smallest_till_now,num) line.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in [-1,-2,5,4,-10,9]:
  if num<smallest_till_now:
    smallest_till_now=num
  print(smallest_till_now,num)
```

Here the print() statement is in the  for loop block not in the if block ..so print is executed for every iteration of for loop irrespective of if statement is true or false

```
smallest_till_now=0
for num in [-1,-2,5,4,-10,9]:
  if num<smallest_till_now:
    smallest_till_now=num
    print(smallest_till_now,num)
```

But here the print statement is in if block.. so it is printed whenever the if statement become true...